# Cannot bind value as INT with PDO pgsql driver

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm running the following code:

```php
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432', 'postgres', 'postgres');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 2154),
            ?
        )
    )
");

$statement->bindValue(1, 4326, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

and am getting the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ERROR:  could not parse proj string '4326'

Looking at the definition of [ST_Transform()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html), I can see that the issue is that PostgreSQL gets the `?` placeholder value as `text` instead of `integer`, which I can reproduce by running these queries in the `psql` CLI:

This works fine:

```sql
    SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 2154),
            4326
        )
    )
```

This gives the error:

```sql
    SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0 0)', 2154),
            '4326'
        )
    )
```

So in all likelihood, the `pgsql` PDO driver ignores the `PDO::PARAM_INT` type given to `bindValue()`, and always passes parameters as strings. I tried with `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` on and off, same result.

**Is this a known issue with the PDO `pgsql` driver?** Or did I miss something?

Comment: Just thoughts: Cast the value in the second parameter to int in the query no matter what is passed? Crude... it should work as a 'get you going fix'.Also, have you tried named parameters in the query and binding. The postgres driver may allow that as standard. I don't have postgres so haven't tried these out. It is just things I would try.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PDO pg driver's [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d4530f807a78d50c2f5fd66114632480e7651d31/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_driver.c#L320), the driver adds quotes to every parameter, regardless of its type.

This is a very old behavior that was even [reported as a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50206), but the report was dismissed since this is the driver's intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I included a cast in the query after the binding, which worked for me

`ST_Transform(geometry, ?::int)`